# Is there any option in insert query to avoid duplicate entry with comparing two fields?

Tags: mysql

Query used here

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, type, tag_type_id) SELECT name, 'open', (SELECT id from types where name = tag_types.name) FROM tag_types
```

It can have values like below

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, type, tag_type_id) ('first', 'open', 2), ('second', 'open', 5), ('first', 'open', 2);
```

I don't want to repeat the entries like above. I need to check whether `name` and `tag_type_id` exists with similar values in table. If exists, avoid duplicate entry.

How to avoid duplication of entries by changing the above query?

I don't have indexes in fields.

Comment: 1. unique index 2. just don't put duplicates in the query, as simple as it is

Comment: @zerkms: I can't make unique for `name` or `tag_type_id`. There values can be changed. I only want to avoid duplication, when combination of two fields come same with existed rows.

Comment: "I can't make unique for name or tag_type_id." --- if you cannot, then you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a unique index spanning the two columns you want to preserve as unique, and then alter your insert statement to read `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` This will prevent the duplicates getting into the table.

```
ALTER TABLE tags ADD UNIQUE INDEX unq_name_type (name, tag_type_id);
```

Then when inserting;

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (name, type, tag_type_id) ('first', 'open', 2), ('second', 'open', 5), ('first', 'open', 2);

INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (name, type, tag_type_id) SELECT name, 'open', (SELECT id from types where name = tag_types.name) FROM tag_types;
```

Hope that helps :)